# How to increase low voltages modified AC Sine wave up to 220 VAC with 0.25 Watt?

Tags: voltage, power, ac, power-electronics, inverter

I am working on Multilevel Inverter and successfully achieved modified sine wave with 7 level, that is much better according to my requirement. But the problem is output AC voltages is too low which is 10-12 VAC. Every thing works fine. Output frequency is 50Hz and required modified sine wave are achieved.
How can I increase this low AC voltages to 180-220 VAC with 0.25 watt?
In Input side I connect 3 individual batteries with 12 Volt DC 1 Amp. Here is the circuit Diagram of my 7-level H-bridge inverter.

[image]
The output modified Sine wave of my result is here.

[image]

Comment: Using a transformer?

Comment: Your schematic shows three 12 V H-bridge circuits connected in series. Why not connect the batteries in series and use one 36 V H-bridge? You are looking for about 1 mA at 220 V AC?

Comment: @LongPham I think you suggest just add 1:22 ratio transformer ?

Comment: @Transistor In Multilevel inverter (MLI) according to design, each H-bridge is required individual  DC battery source.

Comment: @Transistor yes you right. I required just 1mA but 220 VAC . What can I do further ?

Comment: Holy moly! MLC are usually only used for traction and HVDC applications in the MW range. Why on earth would you use it for 250 mW?

Comment: Build a simple sine wave oscillator and drive a transformer!

Comment: @Andyaka I have already modified Sine wave. i need to increase its amplitude from 10 VAC to 220 VAC. suggest me something to fix this problem ?

Comment: If you're only getting 10 VAC from three 12V H-bridges in series, your implementation is horribly inefficient. What is the purpose of this arrangement?

Comment: @DaveTweed to implement the 7 level inverter using h-bridge topology.

Comment: @LongPham thanks Using transformer, voltages are step up. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @winny I have some issue in my circuit, after resolving I get the more than 20 VAC, Thanks for pointing me for this issue. Afterwards using transformer I step up the voltages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the transformer, the voltages are step up and its working. Step up Transformer resolve my issue.